# How to get values after "\n" character?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring, newline

I want to take all values after a new line character `\n` from my string. How can I get those values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *substring = nil;
NSRange newlineRange = [yourString rangeOfString:@"\n"];
if(newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
  substring = [yourString substringFromIndex:newlineRange.location];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at method `componentsSeparatedByString` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

A quick example taken from reference:

```
NSString *list = @"Norman, Stanley, Fletcher";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

this will produce a `NSArray` with strings separated: `{ @"Norman", @"Stanley", @"Fletcher" }`

Comment: That will work, but it seems wasteful - why split into a potentially long array, only to rejoin all but the first element? Jacob's answer, finding the first \n and taking a substring that starts after it, seems better IMHO.

Comment: Actually premature optimization is the root of all evils :)

Comment: Yeah, but choosing a sane algorithm isn't premature optimization. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar function which splits the string by delimeter and return array with two trimmed values.

```
NSArray* splitStrByDelimAndTrim(NSString *string, NSString *delim)
{
    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString: delim];

    NSString *first;
    NSString *second;

    if(range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        first = @"";
        second = string;
    }
    else
    {
        first = [string substringToIndex: range.location];
        first = [first stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        second = [string substringFromIndex: range.location + 1];
        second = [second stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects: first, second, nil];
}
```